# pandas cross table solution

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Using this input

| Gender | SQ2_1 | SQ2_2 | SQ2_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| F | 1 | NaN | 3 |
| F | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| F | NaN | 2 | 3 |
| M | 1 | 2 | NaN |
| M | NaN | 2 | 3 |

How can I achieve this output in pandas using either `groupby`, `crosstab` or `pivot_table`:

|  | Base | M | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All | 6 | 3 | 3 |
| SQ2_1 | 66 .0 | 66.0 | 66.0 |
| SQ2_2 | 83 .0 | 100.0 | 66.0 |
| SQ2_3 | 83 .0 | 66.0 | 100.0 |

The "All" row are the `count()` for gender
SQ2 rows are the percentage by dividing the `count()` of SQ2 divided by All value

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
c = df['Gender'].value_counts()
c['All'] = c.sum()

out = (
 df.set_index('Gender').notna().reset_index()
   .melt('Gender')
   .pivot_table(index='variable', columns='Gender', values='value',
                aggfunc='mean', margins=True)
)
out.loc['All'] = c
```

Output:

```
Gender           F         M       All
variable                              
SQ2_1     0.666667  0.666667  0.666667
SQ2_2     0.666667  1.000000  0.833333
SQ2_3     1.000000  0.666667  0.833333
All       3.000000  3.000000  6.000000
```